# How do I target the "this" element of "this's" child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, parent-child, dom-traversal

Hi I am trying to target "**this"** child descendant of **"this."**

Below is a list that contains sublists.

What I am trying to accomplish is an understanding of how to select **this** child of **this** parent.

Basically when I click on Honda, the sublist expands and I want to console.log the text of each selected element when I click it.  For simplification purposes I changed the code to a console.log.

So far what the code below returns is the text for everything within the li.

***IE*** if I click Honda or If I click Accord, the console returns the values "Honda, Accord, and CRV."

How would I traverse "this" to get the text of the clicked child of "this". The "this" of "this".

***IE*** if I select *"Accord"* using my code below it should return the text *"Accord"* alone.

**Code:**

```
<ul class="main-menu">
CARS
<ul>
    <li class="has-subs">
        <a href="">Honda</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="">Accord</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CRV</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-subs">
        <a href="">Ford</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="">Mustang</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Explorer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$('body').on('click', '.main-menu ul li', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$this = $(this);
console.log($this.text());


if ($(this).find("a").text() == "CRV") {
    var subMenu = $this.siblings('.sub-menu');
    console.log("'THIS' SELECTOR IS WORKING AS INTENDED!");
}
})
```

Update:

Thanks all for answering! I think it will help to explain further what I am trying to accomplish.

What I am ultimately am trying to get sorted out is that I have a master accordion list with a list of car manufacturers and each manufacturer has a submenu like shown above.

I want to click on a list item, say Honda, it expands only Honda's list and shows their makes ie Accord and CRV. Then when I click on either Accord or CRV, it goes to their respective webpages.

When I click on a Ford, Honda's list should collapse or be hidden and Ford's should expand.

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '.main-menu ul li ul li', function (e) {`

Comment: you can just give a class to the sublist element and then adding an eventlistener to that, this would work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes your code work with minimal changes, however note that this setup is problematic since it creates a new (duplicate) event listener on every click.

```
$('body').on('click', '.main-menu ul li', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $this = $(this);
  console.log($this.text());

  $this.on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    if ($(this).find("a").text() == "CRV") {
      var subMenu = $this.siblings('.sub-menu');
      console.log("'THIS' SELECTOR IS WORKING AS INTENDED!");
    }
  })
})
```

As @freedomn-m pointed out, your selectors are probably too broad. I'm not exactly sure what you're ultimately trying to do with the line selecting the sub-menu, but here's an alternate solution that's cleaner:

```
$('.has-subs>a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).parent().text());
});

$('.sub-menu>li>a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/lurutiwago/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Hi Kooc,
Thanks for answering!

What I am ultimately am trying to get sorted out is that I have a master accordion list with a list of car manufacturers and each manufacturer has a submenu like shown above. What I want to have is to have a list of all of the manufacturers only then when I click on a list item, say Honda, it expands only Honda's list and shows their makes ie Accord and CRV. Then when I click on either Accord or CRV it goes to their respective webpages. When I click on a Ford, Honda's list should collapse and Ford's should expand.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty straightforward case where you can use a library like this: [link] https://jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 0):

Your current selector

```
.main-menu ul li
```

will find *all* ul/li, under .main-menu, so will match Honda *and* Accord/CRV.

If you want to only act on the top-level items (Honda), you can change your selector to be more specific:

```
.main-menu>ul>li
```

(assuming they're correctly inside .main-menu).

Or, if you only want the lower ones:

```
.main-menu>ul>li>ul>li
```

or, in your case, target the 'ul' directly

```
ul.has-subs>li
```

or

```
ul.sub-menu>li
```